# Do liquorice roots expire?

Tags: food-safety, storage-lifetime, root

Four years ago I have harvested some liquorice roots in a field. After a brief cleaning with fresh water I have sun dried these roots for a day. These were very tasty. I kept these in a cardboard box. Now are they edible?

Comment: Presumably you dried them four years ago and have just rediscovered them in some forgotten corner of your pantry?

Comment: Yes exactly. This year I found the box and I'm not sure what to do.

Comment: Are they still actually dry? If kept in cardboard, I'd be surprised if they haven't rehydrated somewhat.

Comment: The appearance seems the same of four years ago!

Answer (score 2):

I think that they'd be safe, presuming they're free of mold. However, I'd imagine that the flavor of the roots have likely diminished. Give them a try, let us know how the flavor was after four years in a cardboard box.

Comment: I, too, would consider safe a dried food like these. But I don't know if I dried it in the right way.I fear that something may have generated within the fibers of the roots or some little insect has made its home inside.
I tried a small piece and the taste looks the same! 
However I will let you know if I'll do more testing. Thank you!